# Student Project Ideas using Openstack

Tags: cloud-computing, openstack

I am a student at University and have completed all on my CompSci courses and am getting started in my concentration, security.

What I want to do for my project is create and monitor a secure cloud environment using Openstack. Normally, I would be able to use the Private Cloud provided by my school, but may not be able to do this due to social distancing. Assuming that I do have access, what is a good idea for the project aim, especially for someone who is new to Openstack and the cloud in general? What should the clients of my Openstack orchestrated cloud be using this service to do? Additionally, in the case where I do not have a Private cloud available to utilize, would I be able to undertake a similar project using a public cloud like AWS?